# Was Shiva a minor god during Vedic times?

Tags: vedas, shiva

I know Lord Shiva is one of the Trinity. A lot of temples dedicated to him especially in South India. The god is worshipped by millions. But I came across a link which is about a different proposition. But below are the words which bewildered me.

> Shiva, a Puranic god, started small as Rudra (meaning savage or wild)
>   in the Rig Veda. A minor god, with only two and a half hymns dedicated
>   to him

Below is the full link. 
https://scroll.in/article/844874/how-shiva-was-transformed-from-a-meat-loving-deity-to-a-vegetarian-god

How much truth is there in this article?
Was Shiva really a minor god during Vedic periods ? If the article is false I would like to know
that when was the Trinity first mentioned in Vedas ?

Comment: Hindus do not recognize anything such as Vedic period, the 3 Vedas were given simulataneously according to tradition, indologists believe it. Anyway God knows the rudra of rig Veda is either the shiva rudra or not.

Comment: @SK what do you think about this, the same site you were quoting on me.

Comment: These indologists don't even know that the Vishnu of rig veda is dwarf vamana not Vishnu-narayana. @SK the same writer you were quoting.

Comment: She only writes propaganda. She hasn't learned anything about Vedas, full of anti Hindu bias.

Comment: @Anisha there is certainly vedic era and later puranic era where avataras worship took over vedic deities like mitra varuna Indra etc...